# How to compress and send a large file in an R session opened in a ssh server?

Tags: linux, ssh, compression, tar, r

I'm running an R session in my university server using ssh. I have a large file 17GB> that I can't save because I don't have enough space. I was wondering if there is a way to compress the file in memory without saving it in the drive. Something like instead of writing the *.csv and then compress, save directly the *.tar.gz file in the drive, is this possible?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Is the large file on your local machine and do you want to load it in R? Or is the data in R and you want to save it to a `.tar.gz`  file on the server? Or do you want to save the file directly on your machine?

Comment: Yes for sure, in my ssh R session (remote) I want to save a file directly into my local drive. The reason is that I don't have storage capacity in the server.